# append and execute script to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I'm working with a service provider who holds data externally and provides the snippets below to populate my page with that data. Based on the IDs in the first script, the second script will populate data in the div.

Unfortunately my CMS does not allow external HTML or JS. I'm trying to execute this via Google Tag Manager. Based on other posts on here, I assume I need to execute the scripts and then append the div to the page as new elements. But I'm stumped on how to actually execute it, especially from within GTM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.ex_event_id = 1234;
        window.ex_category_id = 6789;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://register.example.com/js/embed/people_index.js"></script>
<div id="gt_content"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: If your CMS does not allow external HTML or JS ( I'm assuming it's setup out of your control by an Employer or something of the sort ) - just download the file if you know it's secure and serve it locally. Otherwise I'd advise speaking to your administrator.

Comment: This could be a CORS issue

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. See below if curious. This is all done in one tag with `document.write` enabled. There might be more efficient ways of doing this (please let me know if there is!) and I've still got some QA to do, but it seems to work.

```
<script>
    //relabel an existing ID to house the content. Alternatively you could append a div if preferred. 
    //For some reason it wouldn't work if the scripts were added first, 
    //so it's important that the div is made available before appending the scripts.
    document.getElementById("destination").id = "gt_content";

    //append a new script for the IDs
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML = "window.ex_event_id = 1234;window.ex_category_id = 6789;";
    document.body.appendChild(s);

    //append a new script for the URL
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "https://register.growtix.com/js/embed/people_index.js";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this is pretty much the standard way of doing this. The only quibbles would be that this does not require document.write enabled, and that the more common approach is to add the script tags to the head (because the head element is present on every valid HTML document).  document.querySelector('head') will give you the head element, and you can you append operations to that.